# Require module after optimized app.js

Tags: node.js, requirejs, r.js

I'm using `require.js` and optimize it with the node module `r.js`.
It works but I have one problem when trying to require a module after I've included `require.js`.

That's what I need:

```
<script data-main="/js/app-built" src="/js/vendor/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['Functions'], function(Functions){
    console.log(Functions);
});
</script>
```

This doesn't work, as it doesn't find the `Functions` module.
But this works:

```
<script data-main="/js/app-built" src="/js/vendor/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['app-built'], function(){
    require(['Functions'], function(Functions){
        console.log(Functions);
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to achieve the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet the problem is that by the time the first `require` call executes, it is quite possible (quite likely in fact) that RequireJS has not yet loaded your application. The `data-main` attribute initiates right away the loading of your main module but it only *initiates* it right away. The loading is still asynchronous. And the reason it works in your second snippet is that the outer `require` forces the inner `require` to execute *after* your main module is loaded.

So for your `require` call to be successful, RequireJS must have enough information to load it. So it must *already* have a configuration that will allow it to find your module. This either adding some configuration before you load RequireJS. You can set `require` to a configuration object which will be picked up by RequireJS when it is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require = {
    // Enough config to find the main module.
    baseUrl: ...,
    paths: ...,
    bundles: {
        // List here every module you want to load individually. 
        "app-built": ["Functions"]
    }
};
</script>
<script src="/js/vendor/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['app-built']);
require(['Functions'], function(Functions){
    console.log(Functions);
});
</script>
```

You don't have to pull the *whole* config out of your main module because RequireJS can combine configs, but there need to be enough there to allow RequireJS to start loading things. The `app-built` module could contain additional configuration that is not needed for the initial steps. In the code above I've dropped `data-main` and used `require(['app-built'])` instead because I'm not sure whether it is possible to still use `data-main` even when using the `bundles` parameter. (I'm concerned it might confuse RequireJS.) Using `bundles` will allow RequireJS to know that when you require `Functions`, it must find it in `app-built`.

Apart from perhaps still being able to use `data-main` instead of the initial `require` call (which I'm not sure you can do), I do not think it is possible to simplify this further.

Comment: But where is the advantage of a "optimized" file then? If I define, as you suggested, all required paths on top of my site (e.g. `paths: { 'Functions': 'app/modules/functions' }`) each of these files get loaded separately. I think that's not the purpose of `r.js` (my goal is to only have one file loaded..)?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Using `bundles` should take care of that.

Comment: According to your edits I've tried it like this http://jsfiddle.net/k9Sqq/ 
Unfortunately the `functions.js` still gets loaded separately.. See http://oi60.tinypic.com/bikqig.jpg

Comment: Drop the `paths` for `Functions`. I've had `paths` there because I don't know what *else* you might need there. (For intance, if `Functions` uses jQuery, and you load it form a CDN, you'd have to have a path for jQuery there.)

Comment: If I drop the `path` for `Functions` it doesn't find `functions.js` anymore since the module `functions.js` is in a subdirectory of `js/`. You can see my folder structure here http://oi59.tinypic.com/1z348jl.jpg Is it possible to solve that?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of RequireJS? `bundles` was added in 2.1.10. Earlier versions will just ignore it.

Comment: Damn that was the problem... Thank you so much!